# Site Become unavailable when one instance under loadbalancer become unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are using AutoScaling and Elastic Load Balancer from Amazon AWS. We are running three linux(ubuntu) server under a load balancer. When one of the three instance become unhealthy(Status check fails) our site become unavailable.

But other 2 instance was healthy at that time.

Comment: it should not happen. Could you share the logs of ELB and if you haven't enabled them , the refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-access-logs.html.

Comment: No, do not do that. Enabling access logs has nothing to do with troubleshooting ELB issues. login to your instance and use tcpdump on the port to see if you receive any traffic from the ELB at all or not. Also, use curl to connect to instance ip via ELB and request a page. The detailed commands to troubleshoot your problem is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-healthcheck.html

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the actual cause of this problem. Actually `apache` was taking all the memory of the instance. At one point memory exhausted on the machine, so `apache` was not able to serve response.

Following is another question where the problem is described.

[apache2 processes stuck in sending reply - W](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489182/apache2-processes-stuck-in-sending-reply-w)