# apache2 processes stuck in sending reply - W

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4

I am hosting multiple sites on a server with 7.5gb RAM. Using apache2 `mpm_prefork`.

Following command gives me a value of 200-300 in production

```
ps aux|grep -c 'apache2'
```

Using `top` i see only some hundred megabytes of RAM is free. Error log show nothing unusual. Is this much apache2 process normal?

`MaxRequestWorkers` is set to 512

**Update:**
Now i am using `mod-status` to check apache activity.
I have a row like this

```
Srv PID    Acc     M CPU   SS    Req Conn Child Slot  Client VHost Request 
0-0 29342  2/2/70  W 0.07  5702  0    3.0  0.00  1.67  XXX    XXX   /someurl
```

If i check again after sometime `PID` not changes and i get `SS` with greater value that previous time. `M` of this request is in 'W` sending reply state. So that means apache2 process locked in for that request?

Answer (score 0):

On my VPS and root servers, the situation is partially similar. AFAIK the os tries to distribute most of the processing power/RAM to running processes and frees the resources for other processes as the need arises.